# QUdpSocket. How to get the sender's ip address?

Tags: c++, qt, networking

I have a server program that uses QUdpSocket.
 How do I find the ip address of the sender?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From http://doc.qt.io/archives/4.6/qudpsocket.html#readDatagram,

`qint64 QUdpSocket::readDatagram ( char * data, qint64 maxSize, QHostAddress * address = 0, quint16 * port = 0 )`

You pass the addresses of a QHostAddress and a quint16 to the receive function, which get populated with the desired data.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the sender address (and port) when you use the `qint64 QUdpSocket::readDatagram ( char * data, qint64 maxSize, QHostAddress * address = 0, quint16 * port = 0 )` method.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use [readDatagram()](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qudpsocket.html#readDatagram). From the documentation :

> The sender's host address and port is stored in *address and *port
>   (unless the pointers are 0).